# Can I have flexible/catchall regions with Tridion XM/New UI/2012 UI

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I am putting together a functional design for a site which will aims use the Tridion 2012 UI/XM to manage pages. There are 2 regions on the page, a main content area on the left and a side-bar on the right. Ideally users should be able to drag and drop content into and within these regions. In an ideal world I would like to define the regions along the lines of

- Side Bar: any CP for which the CT has the text 'Right' in it.
- Main: all other CPs

Looking at the [documentation](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=UIU4SDLT2011SP1&lang=en-US#addHistory=true&filename=DefiningRegionsOnAWebPage.xml&docid=task_4E5EFDF4775E4A3B8703E912D7C0ED60&inner_id=&tid=&query=&scope=&resource=&eventType=lcContent.loadDoctask_4E5EFDF4775E4A3B8703E912D7C0ED60)  it seems that you need to explicitly use CT/Schema ID pairs to define regions. Is there any possibility to do this in any other way?

At the very least I would like to be able to define that the side bar allows a certain fixed set of CT/Schema ID pairs, but have the main region as a catchall bucket.. Is this possible?

It is also possible that the Side Bar is split into 2 regions, above and below an advertisement. Both regions should allow the same types of CP - as far as I understand this is not possible - is this correct? Are there any ideas for workarounds?

Comment: What if the side bar was a single region that added the advertisement in a certain position? All side bar CPs would just sort in order, with the advertisement included as a CP or in the template markup. Otherwise near-identical templates (side top and side bottom) could work. An alternative hackish approach could be placing side bar CPs based on a field, naming convention, etc.

Answer (score 5):

To configure regions that take all Content Types, You need to get Publication AppData and loop through the content types and build your json markup for enabling this.You could write C# TBB which includes on each page template and does this logic, you can define some metadata at CT level which determines which region it will go in and build the Region JSON markup.

Below is the snippet to get all Component types to add in one region. You could change the logic to get only right just by checking the template name.

```cs
 // get the publication from the engine -- using TemplateBase Util..

    Publication thisPub = GetPublication();

    XmlElement seAppdata = thisPub.LoadApplicationData("SiteEdit").GetAs<XmlElement>();

    XmlNamespaceManager seNsMgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
    seNsMgr.AddNamespace("se", "http://www.sdltridion.com/2011/SiteEdit");
    seNsMgr.AddNamespace("xlink", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink");

    XmlNodeList contentTypes = (XmlNodeList)seAppdata.SelectNodes("//se:ContentTypes/se:ContentType", seNsMgr); 

    List<String> contentTypeJson = new List<String>();
    foreach (XmlNode contentType in contentTypes)
    {
        string templateId = contentType.SelectSingleNode("se:ComponentTemplate/@xlink:href", seNsMgr).Value;
        string componentId = contentType.SelectSingleNode("se:Component/@xlink:href", seNsMgr).Value;

        Component thisSchema = (Component)engine.GetObject(componentId);
        string schemaId = thisSchema.Schema.Id;

        // Add json formated string for Content Types
        contentTypeJson.Add(string.Format("{{schema: \"{0}\", template: \"{1}\"}}", schemaId, templateId));
    }

    // Final Markup - JSON
     String allRegionSeText = string.Format("<!-- Start Region: {{title: \"All Region\",  allowedComponentTypes: [{0}],  minOccurs: 1,  maxOccurs: 5 }} -->", string.Join(",", contentTypeJson.ToArray()));

     // Push to the package to use in DWT..
     package.PushItem("ALL_REGION", package.CreateStringItem(ContentType.Text, allRegionSeText));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I use a similar approach, but prefer marking my regions from within the DWT with the `MarkRegion` functions mentioned here: `http://code.google.com/p/tridion-practice/wiki/TridionUI2012FunctionsForUseInHtmlTemplates`. The sample code only caters for one content type in the region, but you can easily expand it to handling multiple content types.

Comment: Thanks guys for the code examples - however, as I understand it, I would have to republish all my pages every time a new content type (CT and/or schema) is added - right? I kind of wish we had something a bit more immutable like the good old move labels from SiteEdit... Perhaps the next version will allow content type name -> region name mapping to be configured on publication level so we dont have to use the ids...

Comment: Could you output the same region markup, but from a dynamic component presentation called from the page template? This would remove the all-page publishing requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried creating a region without specifying CT/Schema pairs? I remember seeing in an early implementation that you could drop a content type anywhere because regions hadn't been configured properly (or perhaps at all).

Comment: I just tried this and it seems that you cannot drag & drop into a region where there are no component types listed, however if you click the Insert button you can insert the content, and then click Update Preview you will see it (provided your template logic also has a catchall to put the CP in this region)

Comment: Also, the CP cannot subsequently be moved, using the move feature, which is quite a limitation for the implementation I am working with